# Can't deploy Docker container to Azure registry from VSCode

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to follow the steps in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/deploy-visual-studio-code

I've got the plugins setup in VSCode and the sample code cloned to my machine. However, when I right-click on the Dockerfile and select "Build Image in Azure", I'm unable to get it to complete. There's no error, the deployment just seemingly hangs, this is the only output I get:

```
The Docker extension will try to connect to 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock', via context 'default'.
Setting up temp file with 'sourceArchive89321.tar.gz'
   Sending source code to temp file
   Getting build source upload URL
   Creating block blob
Uploaded source code to /var/folders/bn/t9ncw2gx1fxc_2c8h2wb22940000gn/T/sourceArchive89321.tar.gz
Set up run request
Scheduled run ca9
2022/11/02 02:34:13 Downloading source code...
2022/11/02 02:34:14 Finished downloading source code
2022/11/02 02:34:13 Downloading source code...
2022/11/02 02:34:14 Finished downloading source code
2:34:15 Setting up Docker configuration...
2022/11/02 02:34:15 Successfully set up Docker configuration
2022/11/02 02:34:15 Logging in to registry: inhearten.azurecr.io
2022/11/02 02:34:16 Successfully logged into inhearten.azurecr.io
2022/11/02 02:34:16 Executing step ID: build. Timeout(sec): 28800, Working directory: '', Network: ''
2022/11/02 02:34:16 Scanning for dependencies...
2022/11/02 02:34:17 Successfully scanned dependencies
2022/11/02 02:34:17 Launching container with name: build
Sending build context to Docker daemon  173.6kB

Step 1/10 : FROM node:lts-alpine
lts-alpine: Pulling from library/node
213ec9aee27d: Already exists
9653b84b6e0f: Pulling fs layer
78c6f799e789: Pulling fs layer
d64061ca841e: Pulling fs layer
d64061ca841e: Verifying Checksum
d64061ca841e: Download complete
78c6f799e789: Verifying Checksum
78c6f799e789: Download complete
9653b84b6e0f: Verifying Checksum
9653b84b6e0f: Download complete
9653b84b6e0f: Pull complete
```

And it just stays at that final step infinitely, and the image never shows up in the Azure docker registry I specified.

What I tried:
Deploying the docker image to azure

What I expected:
It to successfully deploy

What happened:
It's stuck on Step 1/10 with no error message or obvious way to proceed

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue  in my environment and got the below results***

*I have VS code setup in my local and installed the docker setup*

*Cloning the sample URL Using this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/deploy-visual-studio-code)*

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/containerapps-albumapi-javascript.git
```

[image]

*Signed into the azure and followed the same steps which mention in the document*

*In the explorer window, open the docker file which we have cloned and right click on the Dockerfile and click on* ***Build image***

*While creating the build give the registry name which we have to mention and click on enter it will create the build as shown in below*

[image]

*The docker image got success fully deployed*

*Now we can see the newly created images by using the below command*

```
docker images
```

[image]

***NOTE:***

*1). We are getting these type of errors because of source code not cloned properly for that delete the entire source code and re-clone it again*

*2). please check the versions try to install the latest versions*

[image]